# How to scale / impute a tensor in a `sklearn` pipeline for input to a Keras LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

How can I use `sklearn` scaler / imputer to impute a tensor?  I want to scale / impute within a pipeline.  My input is a 3-d `numpy` array.

I have a tensor of shape (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_feat) a la [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/core/).  This is a sequence that can be learned by an LSTM.  I want to scale / impute first, however.  In particular, I want to scale on the fly inside a sci-kit learn [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), since scaling the full dataset, which would be easy, leads to [leakage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77350/perform-feature-normalization-before-or-within-model-validation).  Keras already integrates w sklearn (see [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-keras-deep-learning-models-scikit-learn-python/)), but there do not appear to be easy ways to scale and impute the tensors that keras time series models process.

Unfortunately, the following gives an error

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[[3,5],[6,2]],[[8.,23.],[7.,23]],[[3, 4],[2, 55]]])
print X
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
s = StandardScaler()
X = s.fit_transform(X)
print X
```

Of the effect, "the scaler only works on 2-d numpy arrays".

My solution was to add a decorator to the sklearn preprocessing data.py file

```
def flat(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self, X = args
            a, b, c = X.shape
            X = X.reshape(a, b*c)
            r = func(self, X, **kwargs)
            if hasattr(r,'ndim'):
                    X = r.reshape(a, b, c)
                    return X
            else:
                    return r
    return wrapper
```

Then use it on the functions, eg `fit`

```
@flat
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    """Compute the mean and std to be used for later scaling.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape [n_samples, n_features]
        The data used to compute the mean and standard deviation
        used for later scaling along the features axis.

    y : Passthrough for ``Pipeline`` compatibility.
    """

    # Reset internal state before fitting
    self._reset()
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
```

This works well; with the same script as above, I get

```
[[[  3.   5.]
  [  6.   2.]]

 [[  8.  23.]
  [  7.  23.]]

 [[  3.   4.]
  [  2.  55.]]]
[[[-0.70710678 -0.64906302]
  [ 0.46291005 -1.13191668]]

 [[ 1.41421356  1.41266656]
  [ 0.9258201  -0.16825789]]

 [[-0.70710678 -0.76360355]
  [-1.38873015  1.30017457]]]
```

But beware, it doesn't check for 2d arrays, which it can't process. So, use the normal preprocessing module for 2d arrays!

Comment: Can you add some data and code of what you are doing?

Comment: Yep, coming soon. I fixed the problem as well I believe, so might interest others. @VivekKumar